# error: invalid operands to binary %

Tags: c

Hola excelente día estoy trabajando en un programa en el que se tiene que adivinar el numero entre 50 y 100.

Al momento de compilar el programa me muestra un error en la siguiente función:

```
o = 50+rand%(352-252);
```

mostrando esto:

```
C:\Users\Elba345\Desktop\adivina el numero.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Elba345\Desktop\adivina el numero.c|15|error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'int (__attribute__((__cdecl__)) *)(void) {aka int (*)(void)}' and 'int')|
```

el código:

```
 #include "stdio.h"     
 #include "time.h"     
 #include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{

int oportunidades,V,A,o,y;

y = 0;
oportunidades = 5;
srand(time(NULL));
V = 0;

o =50+rand%(352-252);

do
{
    printf("%d\n",o);
    printf("Digita un numero tienes 5 oportuniades para acertar\n");
    printf("Los numeros son entre el 50 y 100\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    if(y == o){
        printf("El numero es correcto\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("El numero esta mal\n");
        if(y > o){
            printf("El numero era menor\n");
            getchar();
        }
        if(y < o){
            printf("El numero es mayor\n");
            getchar();
        }
        oportunidades = oportunidades - 1;
        printf("El numero de intentos es: %d",oportunidades);

        getch();
    }
    while(oportunidades > 0);

    return 0;
    }
}
```

¿ Como soluciono el error ?

Comment: Que estas tratando de hacer con ese rand? verificaste como es la llamada a la funcion rand?

Comment: typo: cambia `rand` a `rand()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He retocado un poco tu código para que funcione, básicamente lo que tenias incorrecto era la función para generar números `random`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>    
#include <time.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main()
{

    int oportunidades=5,V=0,y=0,o;
    srand(time(NULL));
    o = rand () % (100-50+1) + 50;

    do
    {
        printf("%d\n",o);
        printf("Digita un numero, tienes %d oportuniades para acertar\n",oportunidades);
        printf("Los numeros son entre el 50 y 100\n");
        scanf("%d",&y);

        if(y == o)
        {
            printf("\nEl numero es correcto\n");
            getchar();
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEl numero esta mal\n");
            if(y > o){
                printf("El numero era menor\n");
                getchar();
            }
            if(y < o){
                printf("El numero es mayor\n");
                getchar();
            }
            oportunidades = oportunidades - 1;
            printf("El numero de intentos es: %d",oportunidades);
            printf("\n\n");
            getch();
        }

    }while(oportunidades > 0);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada, me alegro que haya sido de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Seria bueno que explicaras que cambiaste en el codigo.. si no hay que ir comparando a ojo uno y otro

Comment: Tan solo he cambiado la función `random` para que generase,  números aleatorios entre 50 y 100.